# History of images on Momentum Dash?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to see the history of images from [momentum dash](http://momentumdash.com)?

For example, given a date in the past, can I see which image was displayed?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it on Mac OS X.

Find your extension ID here:
[image]

Pop open the terminal and cd into `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<your chrome profile>/Extensions/<extension id>/backgrounds`

Bonus: type `open .` to open finder to the current directory in terminal. Copy the background images from here.

---

On Windows, the process is similar, except that the path is instead

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<profile>\Extensions\<extension id>\0.95.0_0\backgrounds
```

Comment: Right after the `<extension id>` there comes a version folder, before the `backgrounds` folder. Use `tab` to get the folder name filled in, so you can type `backgrounds` and finally access the folder.

Comment: Any insights on what rules determine which images are stored in this folder? It contains some, but not all previous backgrounds. Few (if any) of the photos in  `chrome://newtab > Settings > Backgrounds > History` are found in the directory location specified.

Comment: More than likely it's deleting the oldest ones. You could unpack the source code and see what it's doing if you wanted to know for sure.

Comment: @NickWoodhams I had assumed so, but strangely the most recent ones aren't there. I'll have a look as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the photo on your momentum dashboard varies from other people with the momentum dashboard, so there is no way of distinguishing a photo for a certain date.

Comment: Welcome.  This site is different from a forum.  On a forum, everyone contributes any information that might be useful.  This site compiles questions and answers as a reference source.  All answers need to be definitive so people looking for them know they can rely on them.  If you aren't sure, you might post the information as a comment (you don't yet have the reputation for that).  You got your impression from somewhere.  If you can confirm that your answer is correct, post it as an affirmative answer (leave off the "If I'm not mistaken", and it would be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I inspect the image, and delete  who were on the image, when I inspect image, found the div her and the code that reads this, copied and pasted to see the address on the same chrome and was changing the numbers of .jpg, and managed to find past several images already in the extension.

The code of background of image is more or less this: chrome-extension://laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca/backgrounds/20.jpg

Copy and Paste this in your address of Chrome and change de number of .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these pictures from your local computer. It is located in background folder of this extension.

For example:
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca\Version(eg:0.42.4_0)\backgrounds (Windows 8.1 Pro)